# What is the difference between partial correlation and removing the linear trend?

Tags: partial-correlation

From this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation, the partial correlation of X and Y can be computed while controlling for Z.

My question is if I removed the regression line between X and Z. and Y and Z and compute for the bivariate correlation of X and Y, would that be the same with partial correlation?